# Graph using ggplot bars with repeated categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the number of days each country has had its schools opened, partially opened, in an academic break, or closed due to covid19, during 2020. When I use the following code I get a graph in which each bar is broken down depending on the time each country has been in each status.

However, countries have been usually changing their statuses many times. For example, Argentina started fully opened, then switched to closed, then went on academic break, it closed again and finally partially opened schools. So I would like each bar to have as many portions as changes (five in this case) instead of only four portions corresponding to the four different statuses.

```
df <- data.frame(Country=c("Arg", "Arg", "Arg", "Arg", "Arg"), Status=c("Fully open", "Closed due to covid19", "Academic break", "Closed due to covid19", "Partially open"), days=c(29, 126, 12, 31, 30))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Country, y = days, fill = Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev)
```

[The graph I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNfoR.png)

Thanks a lot for your help!
Lesbia

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable for the number of changes based on each country like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(Nchange=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Country, y = days, fill = factor(Nchange))) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev)+
  labs(fill='Number of changes')
```

Output:

[image]

Setting same color for some changes:

```
#Code 2
df %>% group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(Nchange=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Country, y = days, fill = factor(Nchange))) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('tomato','green','green','cyan3','magenta'))+
  labs(fill='Number of changes')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Duck! I could reproduce the code, however, is there a way that categories 2 and 3 have the same color? These two represent days closed, but at different times of the study period. I would like them to be separated as they are, but to have the same color.

Comment: @LesbiaMarisG I have added an update, I hope that helps you!

Comment: Duck, thanks for your help, it worked fine. I was wondering, however, if there was a way of doing the same automatically, as in this case each country may have different patterns and hence the meaning of each "Number of changes" may differ.

Comment: @LesbiaMarisG It might be possible, but more data need to be seen for that goal.